# Delete selected item from two list boxes

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a system where once a button is clicked a food item is added to Listbox1 and its price is added to Listbox2. I'm trying to create a button where the user can delete the food item and its price will be deleted.

I'm very new to this but I gave it a go at trying to achieve this task with my code below. The item deletes fine but the first price in the list is deleted, not the price of the item. This is a problem when there are multiple items. The program also crashes if there are no prices

If anyone could help that would be great, cheers

```
 Dim itemdel As Integer

    itemdel = ListBox1.SelectedValue

    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(itemdel)

    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: If your Items don't have any price first add 0 as price on second list so they will have same index. then do as JaredPar said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably both of these values exist at the same index within their relative `ListBox`.  Given that you can just calculate the index and remove both by index

```
Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, this solution don't work to me. my form contain two listboxs
listbox1  contain names.
listbox4 contain ids.
i want select name to delete it and immediately id deleted from listbox4.
after many training. this solution work to me.

```
Dim delname As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
Dim delid As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
If ListBox1.Items.Count <> -1 Then
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
ListBox4.Items.RemoveAt(delid)
ListBox1.Items.Remove(delname)
End If
End If
```

sorry for my weak English skill.