# Re: Delete selected item from two list boxes

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm a bit of a newbie and my question probably has a simple answer... I have searched this site and Google, but haven't found an answer yet? [JaredPar's answer to the above question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787318/delete-selected-item-from-two-list-boxes) seems to be the answer to my current need, but I pasted his code into my program and it gives me the following problem:

```
SelectedIndex is not a member of ListView.
```

This is the only code I have found so far to delete the same selected item from more than one ListView.

I am inserting node text from a Treeview into a ListView and a DataGridView(DGV). When the user inserts the wrong item from the Treeview and decides to delete it both from the Listview and the DGV, the user selects the item from the current list in Listview and clicks the Delete button. This should delete the same item in both the Listview and the DGV to maintain both lists updated. The Listview is used for a visual list during user selection of items by clicking on Treeview nodes. The DGV is used for filtering a saved list of all the items introduced by user in this way.

I was using the following code until I came across the code by JaredPar under the above title, but this only removes an item from Listview. JaredPar's code appears to remove the selected item from 2 Listviews:

```
For i As Integer = ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ListView1.SelectedItems(i).Remove()
Next
```

I hope my question is understandable and that someone can help me with this to be able to learn from your examples! Thanks for any help!

Comment: The most direct equivalents of `ListBox.SelectedIndex` would be `ListView.SelectedIndices(0)` or `ListView.FocusedItem.Index`.  You'd probably use the first option because the focused item may not be selected.

Comment: "The most direct equivalents of ListBox.SelectedIndex would be ListView.SelectedIndices(0)..." Thanks **jmcilhinney**! I tried the SelectedIndices(0) option and it works great! As you say, the ListView item is selected by the user, but the equivalent DGV item is not selected. However, just tested the code using the interface and removing several different items from the list and each time the equivalent item is also removed from the DGV. Thanks man for your help on that!:-)